# How to export/save web pages to/as image?

Tags: iphone, image, uiwebview, web

I try to export web pages to image in order to share it to some social network which not allow to input too many words. When I try to render the layer of scrollview of UIWebview to the current context and create a image, just snap the visible rect of the page. How can I do it? Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *hStr = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"];//get the height
NSString *wtStr = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"];// Get the width
        web.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, [wtStr floatValue], [hStr floatValue]);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(web.frame.size.width,web.frame.size.height));
        CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [web.layer renderInContext:ctx];
        UIImage *finalimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

try setting the webviews height and width according to the pages width and height and then take the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

you may try this way

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(yourwebview.frame.size.width,yourwebview.frame.size.height));
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[yourwebview.layer renderInContext:ctx];
finalimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Its just the way I have tried, but it can only save the visible rect, and what i really want is the content of whole web page.

Comment: there is a uiscrollview in the uiwebview. scrollview.contentSize let you know the maximum size. you can use the other webview(do not addsubview) show this page, and snap this.